# SignalR ASP.NET Core on Service Fabric Fails with HTTP 410 GONE

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-signalr

I have followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) and [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2145770.aspx?ASP%20NET%20Core%202%201%20SignalR%20with%20Reliable%20Actors%20on%20Service%20Fabric) to setup SignalR in a ASP.NET Core web app. Then replicated the same code in a Service Fabric ASP.NET Core service only to find that the 100% working code when hosted outside of service fabric did not work when hosted on Service Fabric. When I open the html client included in both of these samples and turn on developer tools in the browser I see what appears to be the WebSocket handshake failing with HTTP 410 GONE errors.

In the Service Fabric documentation for ASP.NET CORE I found that the ServiceFabric Middleware can return HTTP 410 GONE if the identifier that validates each request does not match. But I guess I don't understand the inner workings of SignalR to know how to properly configure Service Fabric to unblock this.

I am running on a local single node cluster so I figured that I wouldn't have any issues until I needed to do multi-node cluster deployment, at which point I would need to figure out the SignalR backplane I'm going to use.

[image]

Any idea what would cause this to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to disable Service Fabric Integration in the WebHost Builder. Simply replacing this:

```
.UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseUniqueServiceUrl)
```

with this:

```
.UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
```

allowed it to start working.